# staticfiles directory is managed but still it is showing error as "GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1798 while executing the program! and why?

Tags: python, html, css, django, django-staticfiles

I have been used staticfile in the project,

```
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
]
```

which contains *[`css and image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kn6Gv.png)* folders! and connected the *css* file, *`style.css` *,to the html page!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    {% include 'menu.html' %}
    <span class="name">Hello, World!</span>
</body>
</html>
```

But the GET request not fetching the *css* file!

`"GET /static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1798`

I have tried by changing the directory of staticfile,

```
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles/static',
]
```

But still not working!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need ensure that the virtual environment is activated:

```
(venv).................   *your project directory*
```